# Kitematic is stuck at connecting to Docker hub when attempting to download image

Tags: docker, installation, docker-desktop, kitematic

After installing Docker Desktop I tried creating a basic container of "hello-world-nginx". 
I saw container download is stuck, so I created a docker hub account and connected Kitematic to it.

This in turn showed me a spinning Load Indicator with the text: "Connecting to docker hub" that did not end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw [this](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/475) post indicating its a bug.

In order to solve:

1. keep the container that is 'downloading' in the container list (do not remove)
2. Restart Kitematic.